# Invalid literal int() with base 10: '[' when doing a filter with request.body

Tags: python, django

```
def patch(self, request):
        Claim.objects.filter(id__in=request.body).update(....)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I'm trying to update some of my objects this way. But I get

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

so I thought I might need to cast my request.body to list, and I tried it this way:

```
def patch(self, request):
        Claim.objects.filter(id__in=list(request.body)).update(...)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

and I still get the same error.

Why is this happening? If I hardcode it this way:

```
id__in=[8]
```

I don't get any errors.

Thanks.

Comment: `request.body` is a string that contains `[8]`, not a list with an int...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.body` is a *binary string* that contains `[8]`, not a list with an int. You can parse it as JSON with [**`json.loads(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
from django.db.models import Now
import json

def patch(self, request):
    Claim.objects.filter(
        id__in=json.loads(request.body),
        presented_to_client=False
    ).update(
        presented_to_client=True,
        presented_to_client_date=Now()
    )
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```